# Binding Controller Property containing HTML in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

First of all: I am absolutely new to AngularJS but worked on MVC-projects in other languages.

I try to bind a Property containing HTML.

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<p>{{About}}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.About="This is me<br/>and not you!"
}
```

Now the HTML is encoded which I do not want (the `<br/>` should result in line breaks)

I already tried `<p ng-bind-html="About"></p>` but that resulted in no output at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow html in your text which Angular does not by default.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/K4KRCQi4Rpe99MJel5J2?p=preview

[Angular Docs for $sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

> Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) is a mode in which AngularJS requires
>   bindings in certain contexts to result in a value that is marked as
>   safe to use for that context. One example of such a context is binding
>   arbitrary html controlled by the user via ng-bind-html. We refer to
>   these contexts as privileged or SCE contexts.

```
<div ng-controller="htmlChar" ng-bind-html="about"></div>

<script>

  angular.module("app",[])
  .controller("htmlChar",function($scope, $sce){
     $scope.about= $sce.trustAsHtml("This is me<br/>and not you!");
  });

  angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoudln't need to insert html through model binding in AngularJS since the philosophy of the framework is to keep the HTML (page's structure and style) intact and only bind the data to be shown inside that HTML.

If you really need to bind HTML tags into your data you need to use the [$sanitize service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize#!).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use angular compile functionality here, go through the link to get more information [angular compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler#how-directives-are-compiled)